# Zabbix names discovered hosts with IP instead of hostname

Tags: zabbix

I'm bootstrapping a fresh zabbix 3 installation on a dev box.
I've enabled discovery rule for 192.168.1.x setting `Device uniqueness criteria` to *system.uname* (also tried with *system.hostname*). `Checks` are defined appropriately (e.g. `Zabbix agent "system.uname"`).
Also, I've activated the built-in action to assign Linux machines to appropriate host group.
Zabbix server manages do discover a second dev machine configured as zabbix client, but uses the IP instead of hostname for host's `Host name` attribute.

This is inconvenient. So how to configure zabbix to display hostname (or even better fqdn) instead of IP for discovered hosts?

Current client configuration looks like:

```
PidFile=/var/run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid
LogType=file
LogFile=/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.log
LogFileSize=100
DebugLevel=3
EnableRemoteCommands=1
LogRemoteCommands=0
Server=192.168.1.21
ListenPort=10050
ListenIP=192.168.1.11
StartAgents=3
HostnameItem=system.hostname
RefreshActiveChecks=120
BufferSend=5
BufferSize=100
MaxLinesPerSecond=100
Timeout=3
AllowRoot=0
Include=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d
UnsafeUserParameters=0
LoadModulePath=/usr/lib/modules
```

I've already tried to set `Hostname=system.hostname` instead of `HostnameItem` and `HostnameItem=system.run[hostname]`, but this didn't seem to work.

How to solve this?

Comment: Did you tried setting `Hostname` directly instead of `HostnameItem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set your reverse DNS with correct PTR record AND set up hostname in zabbix_agentd.conf

Comment: I couldn't ever verify this, as I've had to use Auto-Registration instead of discovery for other reasons. I assume it could be an issue with reverse DNS, so I mark this answer as the correct one.